# Wordpress plugin Development "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Tags: php, wordpress

Firstly, i know there are a lot of q's about this topic on stack but i can't find the solution for my problem!

I'm developing a plugin which nature doesn't matter and i'm getting "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page".

When it appears?

From a submenu page i'm trying to "send" an id to the same page which i should get to make a specific query.

link from where i "send" the id `http://....../wp-admin/admin.php?page=lse-members-activate`

link where i get the id and the error :`http://....../wp-admin/admin.php?page=lse-members-activate?id=1`

my line :

```
<a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?id='.$res->id.'">....</a>
```

I've tried deactivating, reactivating, renaming pages, modifying slugs etc.

Please, help! :(

Comment: Have you tried using [add_query_arg()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) ?

Comment: Ok, bastienbot. This works! Can you explain to me why my method didn't work?:D

Comment: Hmm maybe because there was already a GET variable in the url ? I can tell you that you better use the wordpress functions, it's pretty hard to know all of them but lit can avoid al lot of trouble...